# Excel not enough memory error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running Excel on AWS EC2 instance R5.4xlarge. I'm having to pull data in a power pivot with sliders from a another sheet containing billing data.  This initial data pull generates about 200,000 rows of data. From that initial data pull, which takes about 10 minutes, I create reports by selecting the client I want data for from their slider. 
I'm able to run about 14 reports by selecting a client from their slider, but then excel gives the 'there is not enough memory to complete this action', it locks up and has to be force quit. I've tried every fix I can find from researching this and nothing has worked, including throwing 16 cpu's at it or memory optimized machines.
I think running a 'save' macro through vba might help clear excel's memory but i'm not sure how to create this.
I found this suggestion on stackoverflow but he didn't include his code text. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396998/how-to-clear-memory-to-prevent-out-of-memory-error-in-excel-vba

"I've found a workaround. At first it seemed it would take up more time, but it actually makes everything work smoother and faster due to less swapping and more memory available. This is not a scientific approach and it needs some testing before it works.

In the code, make Excel save the workbook every now and then. I had to loop through a sheet with 360 000 lines and it choked badly. After every 10 000 I made the code save the workbook and now it works like a charm even on a 32-bit Excel.
It seems that Excel basically purges the memory when you save the workbook. Pretty much like sql purges the transaction log when committing data."

Can someone suggest how I input that type of code and where? And/or do you think this would fix my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade to 64-bit Excel which is now the default for Office 2019. Excel 32-bit can never consume more than 2gb of RAM.

Comment: Improve Virtual Memory.

Comment: I'm running 64 bit, multi-thread over 16 processors on an AWS EC2 instance that has 64GiB.  I've ran this over 6 different AWS instances, including memory optimized and compute optimized.  I don't think hardware is the issue, but rather excel itself, but i'm open to anything at this point.